# What is the educational background of software developers at the SE?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I ask the question because I'm curious to know what kind of background from a technical standpoint does it take to create, manage, scale something like SE. Are there a lot of engineers drawing UML diagrams, programmers pounding away at their keyboards, a bunch of late nights for everybody, etc.

Comment: Their job post says that [employees will never be poked with a sharp stick](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/16279/software-developer-new-york-stack-exchange), so probably pretty good. I can't see dumb programmers ever believing that.

Comment: Your title and the second half of your question appear to be completely different

Comment: Are you asking what it's like to work at Stack Exchange, Inc.? Or are you asking what the backgrounds of the users of Programmers are? Most of us (including the moderators) are not employees of Stack Exchange, but participate freely and voluntarily.

Comment: I have almost zero computer experience minus the HeadFirst Java book I pounded through last month. Just trying to understand the scope of who develops and maintains these ventures. Are they PHDs in computer science or are they a hodge podge mix of backgrounds on the technical team. The question is about gaining a perspective of what goes into a site like SE.

Comment: If you go at [stackexchange.com/team](http://stackexchange.com/about/team), you'll find all Stack Exchange employees. Clicking on their name will take you to their profile, and most of them have a `Stack Overflow Valued Associate #0000x` link in their about box which will take you to a blog post that announces them getting hired by SE, with a short bio. Here's an [example](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-000004/). There are other blog posts that discuss SE internals, but you'll have to scout for them.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, are you seriously asking what the education background is of the Stack Exchange developers?

Our core development team is: Jarrod, Sam, Marc, Emmett, Geoff, Nick, Ben, Kevin, and Rebecca (sometimes). All of them have at least a bachelor's degree from accredited universities. Many of them bring with them years of experience, either at large corporations (pharmaceuticals conglomerates, Microsoft, etc.) or in open source / personal projects prior to joining SE. A number of them were super-major-top users on SO when we pulled them onto the team.

I'm closing this question because, seriously, anything you need to know about our dev team you can find out from http://stackexchange.com/about/team and by checking out their Stack Overflow profiles.